# Ignore destination member in AutoMapper not working

Tags: c#, automapper, abp

I have the following simple classes and mappings that ignore `Id` field.
What I noticed is that the `.Ignore()` does not work when I'm mapping from Eto/Dto to Entity and I do not know the reason behind it.

I'm using the latest ABP 4.4.

```
public class Country : Entity<string>
{
    public Country() {}
    public Country(string id) { Id = id; }
}

public class CountryDto : EntityDto<string> { }

CreateMap<Country, CountryDto>().Ignore(x => x.Id); // id ignored
CreateMap<CountryDto, Country>().Ignore(x => x.Id); // id not ignored
```

Mapping code in my test:

```
var country1 = new Country("XX");
var dto1 = ObjectMapper.Map<Country, CountryDto>(country1);
        
var dto2 = new CountryDto() { Id = "XX" };
var country2 = ObjectMapper.Map<CountryDto, Country>(dto2);
```

I've also tried the normal AutoMapper long form to ignore instead of ABP's `Ignore` extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMapper maps to destination constructors based on source members.

There are several ways to ignore `id` in destination constructors:

1. Map `id` constructor parameter to `null`.

```cs
   CreateMap<Country, CountryDto>().Ignore(x => x.Id);
// CreateMap<CountryDto, Country>().Ignore(x => x.Id);
   CreateMap<CountryDto, Country>().Ignore(x => x.Id).ForCtorParam("id", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (string)null));
```

2. Specify `ConstructUsing`.

```cs
   CreateMap<Country, CountryDto>().Ignore(x => x.Id);
// CreateMap<CountryDto, Country>().Ignore(x => x.Id);
   CreateMap<CountryDto, Country>().Ignore(x => x.Id).ConstructUsing(src => new Country());
```

3. Rename `id` param in `Country` constructor.

```cs
// public Country(string id) { Id = id; }
   public Country(string countryId) { Id = countryId; }
```

4. `DisableConstructorMapping` for all maps.

```cs
DisableConstructorMapping(); // Add this
CreateMap<Country, CountryDto>().Ignore(x => x.Id);
CreateMap<CountryDto, Country>().Ignore(x => x.Id);
```

5. Exclude constructors with any parameter named `id`.

```cs
ShouldUseConstructor = ci => !ci.GetParameters().Any(p => p.Name == "id"); // Add this
CreateMap<Country, CountryDto>().Ignore(x => x.Id);
CreateMap<CountryDto, Country>().Ignore(x => x.Id);
```

Reference: https://docs.automapper.org/en/v10.1.1/Construction.html

Comment: thanks @aaron! i tried #1 and #2 both works.  
still don't quite understand as to why ignore works for entity to eto/dto but not the other way round. essentially it is still a source to a dest. will just keep this in mind =)

Comment: It works for property mapping, but not constructor mapping. If you added a constructor with `id` parameter in your Eto/Dto, then it wouldn't work too.